# Object javascript error

Tags: javascript, object

I am having a problem with my code, I have not been able to figure it out for the past 2 days.

```
 /**
 * 
 *///function 7
/**
 * returns the number of times that pattern occurs in string 
 */
    function score(string,pattern) {
        var v = string.toUpperCase();
        var s = pattern.toUpperCase();
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            var index = v.indexOf(s, i);
            if (index != -1) {
                result[result.length]=index;
                i = index;
            }
        }
        return result.length;
    }

    /**
     * returns an array of records of the form {trackTitle: ..., trackLyrics: ..., trackScore: ...} derived from web. 
     * Each record contains the track title, track lyrics and pattern score of its corresponding content.
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */

    //FUNCTION 9

    function urlScores(music, pattern) { 
        var scoresArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < music[i].tracks.length; j++){
                var itemScore = score(music[i].tracks[j].title, pattern) + score(music[i].tracks[j].lyrics, pattern);


                if (itemScore > 0) {
                    scoresArray[scoresArray.length] = ({indexOfTrack: j, trackTitle: music[i].tracks[j].title, trackLyrics: music[i].tracks[j].lyrics, trackScore: itemScore, album: music[i]});
                }
                itemScore = 0;
            }
        }
        return scoresArray;
    }
    /**
     * Sorts the result of urlScores() into descending order.
     * Records with a score of zero are omitted.
     */

    //FUNCTION 10

    function rankedScores(music, pattern) { 
        var scoresArray = urlScores(music, pattern);  

        function swap(a, b) {
            var temp = scoresArray[a];
            scoresArray[a] = scoresArray[b];
            scoresArray[b] = temp;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
            for(var x = 0; x < scoresArray.length - 1; x++) {

                if (scoresArray[x].score > scoresArray[x + 1].score) {
                    swap(x, x + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        alert(scoresArray);
    }
```

When I run it with the following:

```
  rankedScores(albums, "sparrow");
```

The albums variable is - http://pastebin.com/G25SxrwY

The error is the following -

```
  [object Object],[object Object]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what's the problem? it's alerting exactly what you asked for. what is the expectes result?

Comment: You are asking for the array itself, not its contents, so that is what you are getting.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting an exact duplicate of your previous question, especially when you seem to be making progress on the other one. All you're doing here is starting over and confusing people and potentially yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
alert(scoresArray);
```

No good. You are telling the alert() to output a whole array, but it doesn't know how to output a whole array.

Create a loop to loop through scoresArray and output it that way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to javascript do you mind clarifying what you mean there please

Comment: You are writing to the array in this way: scoresArray[a]...You need to read it the same way. You need to alert(scoresArray[0]),....alert(scores[scoresArray.length-1])